# Query to get only a 3 records of each unique column ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table that lists food types, I would like a run a query to return a maximum of 12 foods but with no more than 3 from each category. Can I do this in one query?

```
category    food    tastyFactor id
seafood     fish    100         1
seafood     prawns  150         2
seafood     crab    50          3
seafood     oysters 300         4
meat        chicken 20          5
meat        pork    100         6
meat        lamb    40          7
meat        beef    50          8
vegetables  carrot  10          9
vegetables  cabbage 300         10
vegetables  potato  75          11
vegetables  parsnip 500         12
```

The foods should be ordered by tastyFactor (the lowest number the earlier in the result set they should appear).

In my example the results should be:

```
carrot
chicken
lamb
beef
crab
potato
fish
prawns
cabbage
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What is the problem with what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION` to combine multiple queries with the same content:

```
SELECT food FROM (
  (SELECT category, food, tastyfactor, id FROM table  
    WHERE category = 'seafood' LIMIT 3)
  UNION
  (SELECT category, food, tastyfactor, id FROM table 
    WHERE category = 'meat' LIMIT 3)
  UNION
  (SELECT category, food, tastyfactor, id FROM table 
    WHERE category = 'vegetables' LIMIT 3)
) AS food_from_cateogry ORDER BY tastyfactor
```

Comment: As an addendum: Add 'LIMIT 3' to the end of each of those separate queries.

Comment: Can you imagine how impractical this solution is?

Comment: Do you have a better solution? Post it and collect your sweet sweet rep!

Comment: I am getting "Every derived table must have its own alias" - looks like I need to enter a name for the table just before the order by

Comment: A better solution? But this *isn't* a solution!! ;-)

Comment: Editted to correct the "Every derived table must have its own alias" error.

Comment: I used this option ... but I needed to add brackets around the individual select queries, otherwise the limits were not working properly

Comment: Edited to add parentheses around queries -- glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know the number of categories in advance, you can still do the query.  You need to start by enumerating the values within each category.  Although you can use variables, I'll opt for the correlated subquery approach for the enumeration:

```
select ft.food
from (select ft.*,
             (select count(*)
              from FoodTypes ft2
              where ft2.category = ft.category and
                    (ft2.tastyFactor < ft.tastyFactor or
                     ft2.tastyFactor = ft.tastyFactor and ft2.id <= ft.id
                    )
             ) as cat_seqnum
      from FoodTypes ft
     ) ft
where cat_seqnum <= 3
order by TastyFactor
limit 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.food
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.category = x.category
   AND y.tastyfactor <= x.tastyfactor
 GROUP
    BY x.category
     , x.food
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
 ORDER
    BY x.tastyfactor
     , x.food;
```

Note, you may want to think a little more about how to handle ties.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using a combo of GROUP_CONCAT and FIND_IN_SET. For large set I i imagine the processing will degrade, but it fairly straightforward for smaller data.

```
SELECT a.food
      ,b.category
      ,find_in_set(a.food, foods) ranking
  FROM food a
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT category,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(food ORDER BY tastyFactor DESC) foods
            FROM food
           GROUP BY category
       ) b ON a.category = b.category
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.food, foods) <= 3
 ORDER BY category
         ,ranking ASC
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8c24/14)